# Vba clear contents of a certain range or cell

Tags: vba, excel

How can I clear the column and row starting with a reference cell?

I used

```
For x = 1 To 20 
    Sheets(1).Columns(x).ClearContents
Next x
```

But I want to be able to clear the contents of all rows and columns starting with row A6 as a reference point. I cant use range since the data is dynamic and changes upon insertion of data. The data came from a csv

Comment: Do you always want to clear from A6 down? Do you want to clear every column? Maybe give a example of what a data output may look like and where you want to clear contents

Comment: You could specify a dynamic named range and then just clear the contents of that range...

Answer (score 2):

Since your question states "I want to be able to clear the contents of **all rows and columns starting with row A6** as a reference point." Then here is a one liner using `SpecialCells(xlLastCell)`

```
ActiveSheet.Range("A6", ActiveCell.SpecialCells(xlLastCell)).Clear
```

Answer (score 0):

**If your range starts at `A6` and is continuous with no blanks in `Row 6` and no blanks in `Column A`, you could set the range like this:**

```
'Create variables
Dim wb as Workbook
Dim ws as Worksheet
Dim rng as Range

'Initialize variables
set wb = ActiveWorkbook
set ws = ActiveSheet
lastrow = ws.Range("A6").End(xlDown).Row
lastcol = ws.Range("A6").End(xlToRight).Column

'Set the range
set rng = ws.Range(Cells(6,1),Cells(lastrow,lastcol))

'Clear contents
rng.ClearContents
```

This uses `Range.End`property of the `Range` object. It's basically like clicking on `A6` and hitting `ctrl+right` on your keyboard and then returning the range.

**Note:** If there are gaps in the range you won't get the correct result.

Comment: application defined or object defined error on the lastcol and lastrow

Comment: @John Apologies, there was a mistake in my code. I've edited my answer please try again.